# ValidateScript unexpectedly returning false when condition is true

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell function I'm writing to build and execute a variety of logman.exe commands for me so I don't have to reference the provider GUIDs and type up the command each time I want to capture from a different source. One of the parameters is the file name and I am performing some validation on the parameter.  Originally I used `-match '.+?\.etl$'` to check that the file name had the .etl extension and additionally did some validation on the path.  I later decided to remove the path validation but neglected to change the validation attribute to `ValidatePattern`.

What I discovered was that while it worked perfectly on the machine I was using to author and validate it, on my Server 2016 Core machine it seemed to misbehave when calling the function but that if I just ran the same check at the prompt it worked as expected.

The PowerShell:

```powershell
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="Server", Mandatory=$true)]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="Client", Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateScript({$FileName -match '.+?\.etl$'}]
[string] $FileName = $null
```

The Output:

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Start-TBLogging -ServerLogName HTTPSYS -FileName ".\TestLog.etl"
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Start-TBLogging : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'FileName'. The "$FileName -match '.+?\.etl$'" validation script
for the argument with value ".\TestLog.etl" did not return a result of True. Determine why the validation script failed,
and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:50
+ Start-TBLogging -ServerLogName HTTPSYS -FileName ".\TestLog.etl"
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Start-TBLogging], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Start-TBLogging
```

Trying it manually worked:

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $FileName = ".\TestLog.etl"
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $FileName -match '.+?\.etl$'
True
```

After changing the function to use `ValidatePattern` it works just fine everywhere but I was wondering if anyone could shed light on the discontinuity.

Comment: `[ValidateScript({$_ -match '\.etl$'})]`

Comment: To reference the value of the parameter inside a `ValidateScript` attribute, you must use `$_` rather than the name of the parameter.

Comment: I plead the "Friday afternoon".  Still begs the question why it ever worked on my windows 10 machine.

Comment: @Matt it probably worked before because you had set a variable `$FileName` in the same session (that is, it wasn't actually reading the same `$FileName` variable). Try it again on your dev machine in a brand new session.

Comment: @briantist Spectacular, I bet you're right.  Thank you both.

Comment: As an aside: There's no point in initializing a string variable to `$null`, because PowerShell, perhaps surprisingly, doesn't allow you to assign `$null` to `[string]` variables; a `$null` is quietly converted to the _empty string_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Joshua Shearer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187982/joshua-shearer) points out in a comment on a question, **you must use automatic variable `$_`** (or its alias form, `$PSItem`), *not* the parameter variable **to refer to the argument to validate inside `[ValidateScript({ ... })]`**.

Therefore, instead of:

```
# !! WRONG: The argument at hand has NOT yet been assigned to parameter     
#           variable $FileName; by design, that assignment
#           doesn't happen until AFTER (successful) validation.
[ValidateScript({ $FileName -match '.+?\.etl$' }]
[string] $FileName
```

use:

```
# OK: $_ (or $PSItem) represents the argument to validate inside { ... }
[ValidateScript({ $_ -match '.+?\.etl$' })]
[string] $FileName
```

As [briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist) points out in another comment on the question, inside the script block `$FileName` will have the value, if any, from the *caller's* scope (or its ancestral scopes).